# How do you set a password on a PDF using Python reportlab and buffer from BytesIO

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I am trying to programmatically add a password to a generated PDF file that is created using Python's reportlab.  The PDF is generated within a Django web application.  The code to dynamically generate a PDF from Django is well documented on Django's help pages:

```
import io
from django.http import FileResponse
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

def some_view(request):
    # Create a file-like buffer to receive PDF data.
    buffer = io.BytesIO()

    # Create the PDF object, using the buffer as its "file."
    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)

    # Draw things on the PDF. Here's where the PDF generation happens.
    # See the ReportLab documentation for the full list of functionality.
    p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world.")

    # Close the PDF object cleanly, and we're done.
    p.showPage()
    p.save()

    # FileResponse sets the Content-Disposition header so that browsers
    # present the option to save the file.
    buffer.seek(0)
    return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename='hello.pdf')
```

But as soon as I attempt to add a password to the PDF file, the resulting PDF file is blank.

```
# This results in a blank PDF document
p = canvas.Canvas(buffer, encrypt='password')
```

Does anyone know how to use a BytesIO buffer with reportlab and set a password on the file?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking in the *wrong direction*.

I have managed to obtain the *encrypted PDF* using the example given by Django Doc itself. Here I am posting an *updated version* of the same

```
import io
from django.http import FileResponse
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas


def sample_view(request):
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer, encrypt="password", bottomup=False)
    p.drawString(100, 100, "This is test encryption !!!")
    p.showPage()
    p.save()
    buffer.seek(0)
    return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename='hello.pdf')
```

### Notes

1. I have set `bottomup=False` which let us write things from top-to-bottom fashion (bottom-to-up is the default behavior)
2. Tested this solution in `Django 3.0`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  I copied your code directly into my project and am still getting a blank PDF file when I open it with the password.  So something else must be going on, but I can't figure out what it is.  I am using Dango 3.1.1 and reportlab 3.5.55.  If I remove the encrypt="password" from your code, the PDF file correctly shows the test message.  Also, I am running in development on Mac OS X, I even tried deploying your code to my test server which runs Ubuntu and I'm still getting a blank document after it accepts the password.  I'm completely stumped.