# pdfencrypt with Reportlab

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I want to add password protection for opening the pdf file from a Django project.

```
def pdf_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="members.pdf"'
    elements = []
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(response, rightMargin=0.5 * cm, leftMargin=6.5 * cm, topMargin=0.3 * cm, bottomMargin=0)
    rows = []
    users = User.objects.all()
    for user in users:
        rows.append((
            user.username,
            user.email,
            user.first_name,
            user.last_name,
            formats.date_format(user.date_joined, "SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT"),
            formats.date_format(user.subscriptions.current_period_end, "SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT")
        ))
    table = Table(rows, colWidths=46 * mm, rowHeights=30, repeatRows=1)
    table.setStyle([
        ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
        ("ALIGN", (0, 0), (-1, -1), "LEFT"),
    ])
    table = Table(rows, colWidths=46 * mm, rowHeights=30, repeatRows=1)
    elements.append(table)
    doc.build(elements)
    return response
```

where can I add this line of code to do encryption

```
pdfencrypt.StandardEncryption("password", canPrint=0)
```

any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Did this solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/66005026/14457833

Comment: No, what I wanted is pdf encryption, so that for opening the pdf doc it ask for password

Comment: Ohh, Sorry I've not added my password version code in that post

Comment: This will solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/65007454/14457833

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the line of code as below

```
def pdf_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="members.pdf"'
    elements = []
    **doc = SimpleDocTemplate(response, encrypt=pdfencrypt.StandardEncryption("pass", canPrint=0)**, rightMargin=0.5 * cm, leftMargin=6.5 * cm, topMargin=0.3 * cm, bottomMargin=0)
    rows = []
    users = User.objects.all()
    for user in users:
        rows.append((
            user.username,
            user.email,
            user.first_name,
            user.last_name,
            formats.date_format(user.date_joined, "SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT"),
            formats.date_format(user.subscriptions.current_period_end, "SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT")
        ))
    table = Table(rows, colWidths=46 * mm, rowHeights=30, repeatRows=1)
    table.setStyle([
        ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
        ("ALIGN", (0, 0), (-1, -1), "LEFT"),
    ])
    table = Table(rows, colWidths=46 * mm, rowHeights=30, repeatRows=1)
    elements.append(table)
    doc.build(elements)
    return response
```